# It is possible that i am login 1000 different device with my gmail account?

Tags: android, gmail

I developed 1 android application ,for food deliver boys and i want to login all the user with same gmail id. My question is ,it is possible 1000 device access single gmail account at a time.

Comment: Contact with google.

Comment: Seriously.  If you are going to build a production system for hundreds or thousands of people to use, based on the services of an email provider, you should not be using the provider's freebie service.  That's not what it is intended for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not Possible.**

[Gmail support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/97150) indicates that it currently has a limit of 15 simultaneous IMAP connections per account.

> Each user account is intended for
>   single use. This means that if you have multiple users frequently
>   accessing the same account or more than one IMAP1 client accessing
>   Gmail at the same time, you may reach a connection threshold and
>   receive the error message, 'Too many simultaneous connections.'
>
> Gmail currently has a limit of 15 simultaneous IMAP connections per
>   account

Hope that helps.